# why activation energy of semiconductor changes as temperature changes

Tags: energy, semiconductor-physics, electrical-resistance

why activation energy of semiconductor thin films changes as temperature changes. I know that this is due to different conduction mechanisms. Intrinsic conduction mechanism which occurs at high temperature and hoping conduction in localized state at low temperature. But I want more information about these mechanism in order to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the activation energy is constant.

There is a boltzmann type term...   $e^{-Ea \over kT}$

where $Ea$ is the activation energy and $T$ is the temperature (and $k$ is boltzmann's constant)

so generally the number of free conductors, $N_{free}$, at energy $E$ can be calculated from the number bound, $N_{bound}$, by something like

$$N_{free}(E) = g(E) N_{bound} e^{-E \over kT}$$

where $g(E)$ is the degeneracy of conductor states at energy $E$.

Note this is for an undoped pure semiconductor.

Note that the minimum *activation* energy $E_a$ is fixed, this is usually the band gap, but as the temperature increases higher and higher energy levels can be populated and so states for which $E > Ea$ will become more and more important.

Edit after useful comments from Jon Custer - and as the temperature changes the band gap can change also. The spacing of atoms generally changes with temperature and thus the electronic structure will change. From a macroscopic point of view we can observe this in the expansion and contraction of solids with temperature.

[image]

Comment: Plus the band gap is a function of temperature, even for an intrinsic semiconductor.

Comment: @JonCuster - good point - I guess this is to do with the vibrational (phononic) motion of the atoms... is that correct?

Comment: The lattice constant is a function of temperature since the potential is (likely) asymmetric, so as the atoms sample phase space (including phonons), they end up preferring a slightly different spacing.  Plus point defect populations change...

Comment: @JonCuster - thanks for your comments - edit made to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If looked at from the point of view of Fermilevel, the Activation energy decreases with increasing temperature. This is due to the raise in the Fermi energy of the material with increasing temperature.

Conduction band may be a higher floor.. you the electron on the JACK board...and the Fermi energy the JACK.... as temperature increases the JACK board raises higher and the height you have to jump decreases.

Comment: can you please edit the second paragraph? I have no idea what you are trying to say,